# Как аккуратно создать двухслойные элементы?

Tags: html, css

Как аккуратно создать двухслойные элементы, чтобы они находились друг под другом, верхний и нижний слой. А то я делаю, они смещаются. Вручную всех чтоли посадить? Думаю есть легкий способ

Answer (score 2):

Если честно немного не понял вопроса.

- Попробуйте создать родительский элемент (section в моём примере) со свойством position: relative;
- В нём поместить 2 (или сколько угодно) элементов с position: absolute; координатами: top: 0px; left: 0px; и различными индексами (z-index)

Должно получиться примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/gpVrJ/

```css
section {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: .5;
}
#first {
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
    z-index: 10;
}
#second {
    background: #0f0;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</section>
```